# How to convert PHP array to be used in JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Hi i have an array like that

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [t_name] => London, Heathrow ) 
        [1] => Array ( [t_name]   => Lilongwe, Malawi ) 
        [2] => Array ( [t_name] => Harare,Zimbabwe ) 
        [3] => Array ( [t_name] => Lahore,Pakistan ) 
        [4] => Array ( [t_name] => Accra, Ghana ) 
        [5] => Array ( [t_name] => Entebbe, Uganda ) 
        [6] => Array ( [t_name] => Nairobi ) 
        [7] => Array ( [t_name] => Abuja, Nigeria )
)
```

and I want it to be converted to be used in JavaScript.
its supposed to look like that
I have tried `json_encode()` but it converts it something like that

```
[{"t_name":"London, Heathrow"},{"t_name":"Lilongwe, Malawi"},
{"t_name":"Harare,Zimbabwe"},{"t_name":"Lahore,Pakistan"},{"t_name":"Accra, Ghana"},
{"t_name":"Entebbe, Uganda"},{"t_name":"Nairobi"},{"t_name":"Abuja, Nigeria"}]
```

but i want it to be converted like that

```
[
 "London, Heathrow",
 "Lilongwe, Malawi",
 "Harare,Zimbabwe",
 "Lahore,Pakistan",
 "Accra, Ghana",
 "Entebbe, Uganda",
 "Nairobi",
 "Abuja, Nigeria",
 "Lagos, Nigeria"
 ]
```

Comment: If you want a different structure in the output, then adjust your input accordingly ...

Comment: how to do that i am using code igniter and the getting the results from database and this is how it returns me the array and when i convert it, it does not work accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before `json_encode` your array you need to get first the values of that single column which is `t_name` using `array_column` and echo the resultant array. Try it as

```
$arr = Array (Array ( 't_name' => 'London, Heathrow' ),Array ( 't_name'   => 'Lilongwe, Malawi' ),Array ( 't_name' => 'Harare,Zimbabwe' ),Array (   't_name' => 'Lahore,Pakistan' ),Array ( 't_name' => 'Accra, Ghana' ),Array ( 't_name' => 'Entebbe, Uganda' ),Array ( 't_name' => 'Nairobi' ),Array ( 't_name' => 'Abuja, Nigeria' ));
echo json_encode(array_column($arr,'t_name'));
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/394083)

Comment: i am getting the result array from the database by using the codeigniters own methods and above is what it returns

Comment: You might be storing that array within variable just place that variable within as `echo json_encode(array_column($your_array,'t_name'));` and that's it if the value that you have posted within your question looks like that then it'll surely work

Comment: okay both your and @Barmar way work gives me the arrays but there are spaces in them now how to remove them i am basically want to use them in auto-complete input feild.

Comment: Can you please show some text where you were getting space

Comment: its done i have managed it. BTW how do i delete my post. ?

Comment: You can't for explanation [how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow) . _(FYI:You can accept one of these answer or upvote an answer which really helped you. Thank You)_

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to extract the names into a simple array:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    $new_array[] = str_replace(' ', '', $obj['t_name']);
}
echo json_encode($new_array);
```

Comment: there are spaces in them how to remove them?

Comment: Why do you need to remove them? You have spaces in the desired output.

Comment: But if you want to use them, use `str_replace()`. WTP?

Comment: i am creating an autocomplete input feild so the spaces will be a mess in them and how to use srt_replace() in arrays i have used it for strings but not for arrays

Comment: Use it on the strings when you're assigning them to the array. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Why did you show the spaces in the desired output if you wanted them removed?